# XSL in script tags

Tags: javascript, xslt

I need to output XSL in between script tags to dynamically output values into JavaScript.

Here is the code, but I can't get it to work. I want to add the `position()` into the script so it outputs something like `o.write("flash1");` and increments the number per each flash file embedded. Any help appreciated.

```
<div>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">iframe-content<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
  <div id="flash"></div><!--/flash-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[ 
    var so = new SWFObject("swf/video2.swf", "showreel", "720", "484", "8", "#ffffff");
    so.addParam("quality", "high");
    so.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "always");
    so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    so.addVariable("videoURL", "http://www.masterseries.co.uk/public/TempFiles/Concrete1.flv");
    so.write("flash");
    // ]]>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close (you just can't easily use CDATA the way you did):

```
<!-- note that you don't need xsl:attribute here -->
<div id="iframe-content-{position()}">
  <div id="flash"></div><!--/flash-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("swf/video2.swf", "showreel", "720", "484", "8", "#ffffff");
    so.addParam("quality", "high");
    so.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "always");
    so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    so.addVariable("videoURL", "http://www.masterseries.co.uk/public/TempFiles/Concrete1.flv");
    so.write("flash<xsl:value-of select='position()' />");
  </script>
</div>
```

You can use

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="script"/>
```

to create CDATA sections in the output. However, you must make sure the input script source is correctly XML-encoded, i.e. does not have bare `<`, `&`, `>` characters but their `&lt;`, `&amp;`, `&gt;` equivalents.

Comment: That's fantastic. This has been bugging me for ages. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Tomalak: Seems a good answer, but aren't there too-many nested quotes in `so.write` ?

Comment: @Dimitre: It's syntactically valid (I've tested it), just the SO syntax highlighter can't cope with it.